# Крайний и последний

Tags: прилагательные, разница

> Поэтому когда отец пьёт с друзьями, они поднимают тост за то, чтобы количество взлётов совпадало **бы** с количеством посадок. У них было ещё много тостов, и ещё было правило не говорить **"последний"**, а говорить **"крайний"**

(В. Березин - Путевые знаки)

1. Почему здесь добавочное *бы*? (я бы сказал *чтобы количество взлётов совпадало с количеством посадок*?
2. В чём разница между *последний* и *крайний*? Что здесь имеется в виду?

Comment: пожалуйста, старайтесь в рамках одного поста задавать один вопрос.

Comment: Не во всех регионах России лётчики используют слово "крайний" вместо "последний"- это навязанный Инетом стереотип.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. Можно и без "бы". Сослагательное наклонение здесь подчёркивает, то, что это пожелание.
2. В России, среди людей занятие которых связано с риском, не принято говорить "последний" (полёт), так как точно таким же образом скажут о  смерти. Стандартный эвфемизм на смерть кого-либо - *"отправился в последний путь"*. В итоге, у людей, связанных с опасной для жизни деятельностью (в данном тексте лётчики) стали говорить "крайний", хотя это и не литературная норма.

Comment: я бы только хотел добавить, что даже среди людей, профессия которых связана с опасной деятельностью, далеко не все говорят "крайний" вместо последний - некоторых раздражает такая суеверность.

Comment: Чаще просто заменяют "последний" на "крайний" в речи всегда. Встречал, например, вопросы "это ушёл крайний автобус?" Нет, это ушёл последний :(

Comment: "крайними бывают плоть, Север, мера, срок и необходимость"

Answer (score 4):

"Последний полёт" (лётчики), "последний прыжок" (парашютисты, прыгуны с трамплина) , "последний рейс" (моряки), "последнее погружение" (дайверы, водолазы), "последнее восхождение" (альпинисты) и так далее. Люди названных профессий, видов спорта или увлечений НЕ говорят так из суеверия, боясь сглазить и вследствие этого погибнуть.

Answer (score 3):

**Крайний** - находящийся на границе какого-нибудь объекта (или интервала, диапазона): *крайнее окно справа*, *крайнее недовольство* (недовольство на границе всех возможных уровней недовольства).

**Последний** - имевший место позднее всех по времени (*последний поезд*) или такой объект в ряду похожих, после которого эти объекты кончаются (*последний патрон*).

Иногда, смысл этих слов совпадает. Например, *крайний в очереди* является так же и *последним в очереди*, хотя второй вариант, на мой взгляд, является предпочтительным.

В связи со своим значением слово **последний** породило суеверие (изначально у представителей профессий, связанных с повышенным риском), основанное на представлении о том, что если назвать какое-либо событие *последним*, оно станет последним в жизни говорящего или другого связанного с ним человека.

К сожалению, привычка неправильного употребления *крайний* вместо *последний* чрезвычайно распространилась в посдледние 20 лет и среди обывателей.

Comment: да, я уже жду, когда в издательстве "Библиотека Вооруженных Сил" появится книга "Крайний из могикан".